# ssrs parameters visibility

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I m using ssrs on sql 2008.My question maybe utopic.

I want to make this situation,i have two parameters,named xParameters and yParameters.both of them loaded from datasets like combobox.

I want to make like dropdownlist selectedchanged event on c#.If i selected xParameters then hide yParameters.Also this state valid of yParameters.Then execute query on selected query.

Is it possible.

Note:I wrote a query,if bParameters is not null then Xquery,else Yquery,but i want to hide other parameters on forms when a parameters selected.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if you can change the visibility of parameters in SSRS.

No, with the built-in SSRS interface you cannot dynamically hide and show parameters.

Potential workarounds:

- You can build your own interface and call the web services to pass your parameters in and display the results in your interface.
- Can you combine the two parameter lists into one, so that the user is forced by the drop down to select just one item?
- Catch invalid entries for the parameters and show an error text box on the report (Big red print) that explains what the user did wrong.

Comment: yes,@Jamie u undestood correctly,thanks answer,but i dont use any web service,i wanted to buit-in ssrs interface.But it s not possible :( .Thanks ur advice.